# Inverse transform method on MCMC generated uniform draws

Tags: references, markov-chain-montecarlo, monte-carlo, uniform-distribution, quasi-monte-carlo

I understand that it sounds like why would anyone do this, but are there any references that use the inverse transform method to draw correlated samples from a distribution $F$ using MCMC samples from $U[0,1]$ or even QMC generated draws from $U[0,1]$?

Comment: Sounds interesting. Inverse of CDFs are used to transform uniform random samples to random samples of other distributions. I don't understand what you mean with correlated samples. Do you want to use a bivariate distribution F?

Comment: I assume if the draws from $U[0,1]$ are correlated, then the resulting transformed draws from $F$ are also not correlated. That's all I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many references for using QMC within MCMC. For instance,

[Sequential quasi-Monte Carlo: Introduction for Non-Experts, Dimension Reduction, Application to Partly Observed Diffusion Processes
by Nicolas Chopin & Mathieu Gerber](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.05305)

[A Quasi-Monte Carlo MetropolisAlgorithm by Art B. Owen & Seth D. Tribble](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~owen/reports/qmcmcmc.pdf)

[Quasi-Monte Carlo methods for Markov chains with continuous multi-dimensional state space. Math. Comput. Simul. 81(3): 560-567 (2010), by Rany El Haddad, Christian Lécot, Pierre L'Ecuyer, & N. Nassif](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0378475410002648?via%3Dihub)

If the purpose is in using MCMC towards drawing correlated uniforms to then invert them into correct marginals with some unknown degree of correlation, I do not see the reason for doing this, as the correlations at the uniform and transformed variates level are not controlled. A copula approach would at least control the correlation for the uniforms.

Comment: Thanks Xi’an. Nothing with MCMC?

Comment: I agree it doesn’t sound useful. So you’re saying, you don’t know of literature on this?

Comment: no, nothing at all.